# How am I supposed to pass an unpaged but sorted Pageable to a Spring JPA repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

Spring JPA has the Pageable interface. I can pass this to a repository method. Some of its implementations like `PageRequest` contain a `page`, a `size` and a `sort`. However, there is also an `unpaged` instance that I can create with `Pageable.unpaged()` and that returns an `org.springframework.data.domain.Unpaged` which is an enum that implements Pageable.

The problem comes when you want to make use of the sorting abilities of this pageable object, but do not want paging. In that case you should want the `Pageable.isPaged()` to return false, however the only instance of this that you can normally create is the PageRequest (with `Pagerequest.of(size, page, sort)`) which always returns true for that method.

If you have a JPA repository method like this:

```
Page<EventTriggerVersion> findByProjectIdAndEventTriggerId(
    @Param("projectId") UUID projectId, @Param("eventTriggerId") UUID eventTriggerId, Pageable pageable);
```

Then you cannot create a Pageable for it that DOES sort but DOES NOT page, i.e. returns only 1 page with all results.

However, you can ALSO not just give it both a unpaged Pageable AND a Sort param, if you do then it throws this exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method must not have Pageable *and* Sort parameter. Use sorting capabilities on Pageable instead!`

So how am I supposed to do this without duplicating all my repository methods (which mostly have custom queries) to have a version with Pageable and with Sort?

Our users simply want to pass `size=0` in their request and then get all data (not limited to some arbitrary maximum but a genuine unpaged request). This is annoying enough because it means I need to remove the Pageable request param from the controller and manually construct it from page, size and Sort, but now it doesn't even seem possible without serious code duplication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For now I implemented my own Pageable class as following:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;

public class SortedUnpaged implements Pageable {

    private final Sort sort;

    private SortedUnpaged(Sort sort) {
        this.sort = sort;
    }

    public static SortedUnpaged getInstance(Sort sort) {
        return new SortedUnpaged(sort);
    }

    public boolean isPaged() {
        return false;
    }

    public Pageable previousOrFirst() {
        return this;
    }

    public Pageable next() {
        return this;
    }

    public boolean hasPrevious() {
        return false;
    }

    public Sort getSort() {
        return sort;
    }

    public int getPageSize() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public int getPageNumber() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public long getOffset() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public Pageable first() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And have this in my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/{projectId}" + SUBJECTS_PATH)
public ResponseEntity<SubjectWrapperDTO> getSubjects(
    @RequestParam(name = "size", required = false, defaultValue = "20") Integer size,
    @RequestParam(name = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer page,
    @SortDefault(sort = "name") Sort sort) {

    Pageable pageable;
    if (size > 0) {
        pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size, sort);
    }
    else {
        pageable = SortedUnpaged.getInstance(sort);
    }
    ...

}
```

But this seems to be a bit too much for such a basic requirement and I'd prefer not implementing my own classes of Spring interfaces.

Comment: Very good question, I found some related github tickets: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2691, this does not seem to be fixed.

Comment: Did you find out anything so far as this post is a bit older already?

Comment: Also note according to the ticket I provided sort, limit and offset should not work with this custom implementation. If it did so anyway can you explain how that worked?

Comment: @judos I don't know why it wouldn't work, it does. Have you tried it with this solution? Since it's just an abstraction anyway, I didn't have to do anything else, Hibernate just generates the query.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek Your solution do not work indeed, since your class implementation return `false` when `isPaged()` is called. This causes the SimpleJpaRepository class to create a new PageImpl with an Pageable.unpaged() instance instead, which does apply the custom Sort...
You can check it here : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/spring-data-jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L448

Comment: @Tazaf that only seems to be the case for the provided `findAll` methods,  I'm using the Pageable in my self-defined repository queries and it works there as a way to enable sorting. But it would be great if Spring provided a way to do this otherwise.